# Export DCP from Adobe premier pro

Tags: video-editor, video-quality, adobe-media-encoder

Hey guys I’m struggling to export feature film  2hour 20 min long DCP from premier pro.

1.I already exported 422 Hq.
2.Made separate project with new sq.
3.Using Adobe encoder as well.
4.Every time my Mac frozen at 13%.

All movie we shot on IPhone
1920*1080

My Mac
16gb
3.8 ghz intel core i7
1Tb hard drive

For editing I using regular external hard drive on 4tb.

Do you have any suggestions how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a few things to try. I've never experienced any export getting stuck, so my advice is a bit generic.

1. Enable "Preview while Encoding" in Media Encoder's preferences. But it should be on by default.
2. Using the preview, find the clip in the sequence where the export gets stuck.
3. Find out what is different with this clip compared to the earlier clips or portion of the sequence.
4. Disable all effects on that clip and try exporting again. If this works replace any problematic effect with something equivalent.
5. Otherwise, replace the footage with a transcoded version of the clip, use something like ProRes with constant frame rate. There are some issues with variable frame rate footage in Premiere and After Effects and I assume your iPhone recordings use variable frame rate.
6. Try exporting on another system or try another DCP exporter plugin.
7. Contact Adobe for support if nothing else helps or find a service provider that creates the DCP for you.